# How do you get rid of Hz when calculating MIPS?

Tags: math, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'm learning computer structure.
I have a question about MIPS, one of the ways to calculate CPU execution time.

The MIPS formula is as follows.

[image]

And if the clock rate is 4 GHz and the CPI is 1.
I think MIPS is 4,000hz.

Because It's 4 * 10^9 * Hz / 1 * 10^6.

I don't know if it's right to leave units of Hz.

Comment: It would be 4,000 **M**Hz (because it says Instruction time **x 10^6**), which is equal to 4GHz anyway, which also makes sense in your example because CPI=1 (1 cycle per instruction means they are equal). Technically Hz as base unit (MHz in this case because of 10^6) would be fine because it just means "something per second", which won't differentiate between cycles and instructions, but because the (M/G)Hz unit is usually associated with _cycles_ per second when it comes to processors, it's better to use the (M)IPS unit (instructions per second) explicitely, so it would be 4,000 MIPS.

Comment: (Hz IPS wouldn't make sense because both mean the same if you break them down to SI units - the PS stands for "per second" which is same thing Hz means. The result should be <instructions> s⁻¹ and not <instructions> s⁻².)

Comment: Thank you for answering my poor English. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any quantity, it's important to know what units it's in.  As well as a scale factor (like a parsec is many times longer than an angstrom), units have **dimensions**, and this is fundamental (at least for physical quantities like time; it can get less obvious when you're counting abstract things).

Those example units are both units of length so they have the same dimensions; it's physically meaningful to add or subtract two lengths, or if we divide them then length cancels out and we have a pure ratio.  (Obviously we have to take care of the scale factors, because 1 parsec / 1 angstrom isn't 1, it's `3.0856776e+26`.)  That is in fact *why* we can say a parsec is longer than an angstrom, but we can't say it's longer than a second.  (It's longer than a light-second, but that's not the only possible speed that can relate time and distance.)

1 m/s is not the same thing as 1 kg, or as dimensionless 1.

---

Time (seconds) is a dimension, and we can treat instructions-executed as another dimension.  (I'll call it `I` since there isn't a standard SI unit for it, AFAIK, and one could argue it's not a real physical dimension.  That doesn't stop this kind of dimensional analysis from being useful, though.)

(An example of a standard count-based unit is the [mole in chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)), a count of particles.  It's an SI base unit.)

Counts of clock cycles can be treated as another dimension, in which case clock frequency is cycles / sec rather than just s<sup>-1</sup>.  (Seconds, *s*, are the base SI unit of time.) If we want to make sure we're correctly cancelling it out in both sides, that's a useful approach, especially when we have quantities like cycles/instruction (CPI).  Thus cycle time is s/c, seconds per cycle.

Hz has dimensions of s<sup>-1</sup>, so if it's *something* per second we should not use Hz, if *something* isn't dimensionless.  (Clock frequencies normally are given in Hz, because "cycles" aren't a real unit in physics.  That's something we're introducing to make sure everything cancels properly).

**MIPS has dimensions of `instructions / time` (`I / s`), so the factors that contribute to it must cancel out any cycle counts.**  And we're not calling it Hz because we're considering "instructions" as a real unit, thus 4000 MIPS not 4000 MHz.  (And MIPS is itself a unit so it's definitely not 4000 Hz MIPS; if it made sense to combine units that way, that would be dimensions of I/s<sup>2</sup>, which would be an acceleration not a speed.).

From your list of formulas, leaving out the factor of 10^6 (that's the M in MIPS, just a metric prefix in front of Instructions Per Sec, `I/s`)

- `instructions / total time` obviously works without needing any cancelling.
- `I / (c * s / c)` = `I / s` after cancelling cycles in the denominator
- `(I * c/s) / (I * c/I)` cancel the Instructions in the denominator:
  `(I * c/s) / c`  cancel the cycles:
  `(I * 1/s) / 1` = `I/s`
- `(c/s) / (c/I)` cancel cycles:
  `(1/s) / (1/I)` apply `1/(1/I)` = `I` reciprocal of reciprocal
  `(1/s) * I` = `I / s`

**All of these have dimensions of Instructions / Seconds**, i.e. I/S or IPS.  With a scale factor of 10<sup>6</sup>, that's MIPS.

---

**BTW, this is called "dimensional analysis"**, and in physics (and other sciences) it's a handy tool to see if a formula is sane, because both sides must have the same dimensions.

e.g. if you're trying to remember how position (or distance-travelled) of an accelerating object works, `d = 1/2 * a * t^2` works because acceleration is `distance / time / time` (e.g. m/s^2), and time-squared cancels out the `s^-2` leaving just distance.  If you mis-remembered something like `1/2 a^2 * t`, you can immediate see that's wrong because you'd have dimensions of `m / s^4 * s` = `m / s^3` which is not a unit of distance.

(The factor of 1/2 is not something you can check with dimensional analysis; you only get those constant factors like 1/2, pi, e, or whatever from doing the full math, e.g. taking the derivative or integral, or making geometric arguments about linear plots of velocity vs. time.)

Comment: Thanks to you, I learned a lot. The difference between the cycle per sec and the instruction per sec was exactly where I was confused.

Answer (score 4):

Hz is 1/s.  MIPS is actually "mega instruction / s".  To be clear, "Per" is the slash for division:  **Mega Instructions / Second**

4GHz is 4G s⁻¹.  Divide that by 1 cycle per instruction... but *cycle* is period, which is inverse of frequency.

It's not 4000Hz MIPS because the MIPS means "Per second".  You wrote 4000 million instruction 1/s 1/s.

You eat the Hz because it's part of the name you are labeling it with.

Comment: For some reason, my comment was erased. You answered really quickly, correcting what I misunderstood. Thank you so much.